# Calculating infinite sum using Parseval's theorem

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, analysis, fourier-series, complex-integration

For$\alpha \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Z}$, consider the fnunction $[0,2\pi] \to \mathbb{C} : x \mapsto \frac{\pi}{\sin \pi \alpha} e^{i(\pi - x)\alpha}$, and prove that $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+\alpha)^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{(\sin \pi \alpha)^2}$. Recall that $\{x \mapsto (2\pi)^{-1/2} e^{inx} : n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is an orthonormal basis for $L^2_\mathbb{C}[0,2\pi]$

**My Attempt**:

We use **Parseval's Theorem**, the fact that $\|f\|^2 = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} |\langle f,e_n \rangle|^2$, with the inner product norm on $L^2_\mathbb{C}[0,2\pi]$. Firstly, we compute the left-hand side. We have 
\begin{align*}
\|f\|^2 & = \int_0^{2\pi} f(x)^2 dx = \frac{\pi^2}{(\sin \pi \alpha)^2} \int_0^{2\pi} e^{2i(\pi - x)\alpha} dx \\
& = \frac{\pi^2}{(\sin \pi \alpha)^2} e^{2i\pi\alpha} \int_0^{2\pi} e^{-2ix \alpha} dx
= \frac{\pi^2}{(\sin \pi \alpha)^2} e^{2i\pi\alpha} \left[ -\frac{1}{2i\alpha}e^{-2ix \alpha} \right]_0^{2\pi} \\
& = \frac{\pi^2}{(\sin \pi \alpha)^2} e^{2i\pi\alpha} \left( -\frac{1}{2i\alpha}e^{-4i\pi \alpha} + \frac{1}{2i\alpha} \right) = 
\frac{\pi^2}{(\sin \pi \alpha)^2} e^{2i\pi\alpha} \left( \frac{1 - e^{-4i\pi \alpha}}{2i\alpha} \right) \\
& = \frac{\pi^2}{(\sin \pi \alpha)^2} \left( \frac{e^{2i\pi\alpha} - e^{-2i\pi \alpha}}{2i\alpha} \right)
= \frac{\pi^2}{(\sin \pi \alpha)^2} \left( \frac{\sin (2\pi \alpha)}{\alpha} \right)
= \frac{2 \pi^2 \cos (\pi \alpha)}{\sin (\pi \alpha) \alpha}. 
\end{align*}
Here we use the trigonometric identities 
$$
\sin \beta = \frac{e^{i\beta} - e^{-i\beta}}{2i}, \ \textrm{ and } \ \sin(2\beta) = 2\sin(\beta)\cos(\beta). 
$$
On the left-hand side we have 
\begin{align*}
\langle f,e_n \rangle & = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{inx} \frac{\pi}{\sin \pi \alpha} e^{i(\pi - x)\alpha} dx = \frac{\pi}{\sin (\pi \alpha) \sqrt{2\pi}} \int_0^{2\pi} e^{inx + i(\pi - x)\alpha} dx \\
& = \frac{\pi}{\sin (\pi \alpha) \sqrt{2\pi}} e^{i \pi \alpha} \int_0^{2\pi} e^{(in- i\alpha)x} dx
= \frac{\pi}{\sin (\pi \alpha) \sqrt{2\pi}} e^{i \pi \alpha} \left[ \frac{1}{in - i\alpha} e^{(in- i\alpha)x} \right]_0^{2\pi} \\
& = \frac{\pi}{\sin (\pi \alpha) \sqrt{2\pi}} e^{i \pi \alpha} \left( \frac{1}{in - i\alpha} e^{(in- i\alpha)2\pi} - \frac{1}{in - i\alpha} \right) \\
& = \frac{\pi}{\sin (\pi \alpha) \sqrt{2\pi}} e^{i \pi \alpha} \left( \frac{e^{i(n-\alpha)2\pi} - 1}{i(n - \alpha)} \right) = \frac{\pi}{\sin (\pi \alpha) \sqrt{2\pi}} \left( \frac{-(e^{i \pi \alpha} - e^{-i\pi\alpha})}{i(n - \alpha)} \right) \\
& = \frac{\pi}{\sin (\pi \alpha) \sqrt{2\pi}} \frac{-2 \sin(\pi \alpha)}{n - \alpha} 
= \frac{-2\pi}{(n-\alpha)\sqrt{2\pi}}
\end{align*}
Hence, we have that 
$$
|\langle f,e_n \rangle|^2 = \frac{2\pi}{(n-\alpha)^2}. 
$$

This is what I tried, things don't seem to add up to the desired outcome and I can't find any mistakes. Anyone has suggestions? I find the computations I made rather laborious, perhaps there are some tricks to do this simpler? I'm not so familiar with trigonometry and complex integration. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe the norm of $f$ should be an integral of $|f|^2$, and not merely $f^2$

Comment: Isn't the inner product on $L^2[a,b]$ defined as $\langle f,g \rangle = \int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx$?
Also, what would be $|e^{i(\pi-x)\alpha}|^2$?

Comment: That is the inner product when the functions are real-valued. If they are complex-valued, it is $\langle f,g\rangle =\int_a^b f(x)\overline{g(x)}\, dx$.

Comment: Oh yeah you're right. How to compute absolute value of complex e-powers though?

Comment: Use the fact that if $t$ is any real number, then $\boxed{\color{blue}{\left|e^{it}\right| =1}}$. This can be shown by using Euler's formula ($e^{it} = \cos t +i \sin t$) and the identity $\cos^2 t + \sin^2 t =1$.

Comment: Oh! So the whole term $|e^{i(\pi - x)\alpha}| = 1$?

Comment: Correct! $\ddot{\smile}$

Comment: Thanks! That seems to save a lot of hassle, I should have known that several hours earlier :-)

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth I tried bending my head to the right, tried bending to the left, I still don't get this smiley.

Comment: No need to bend the head -- it's a smiley that is not rotated.